# Excel VBA - Copy data from summary - sheet names as variables

Tags: excel, vba

Cells E7:E17 contain values of existing sheet names. Subsequent columns contain data to be copied to corresponding worksheet.
Ex. E7 value is Case 1 
F7:H7 contain data to be copied to sheet called "Case 1"
Is it possible to cycle the sheetname as a variable?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX0pv.jpg)

Comment: Yes, `Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Range("E7")).Range("F7:H7") = Sheets("Summary").Range("F7:H7")`

Comment: Where in the new sheet would you like the copied data to be copied to ?
It is possible to cycle through the cells E7:E17, and use their values as names for which sheet to copy to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still need it, the following code will cycle through the cells E7:E17, and uses their values as the sheet names.

It will then take the data in the three columns to the right of that cell, and copy the data to cells A1:C1 on the sheet with the cells value.

```
Sub test()

Dim cell As Range, startSheet As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

startSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

For Each cell In Sheets(startSheet).Range("E7", "E17")

    If Not cell.Value = Empty Then
        Sheets(cell.Value).Range("A1:C1") = Sheets(startSheet).Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 4))
    End If

Next cell


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```